# GRG Nonlinear R

Tags: r, optimization, distance

I want to transform my excel solver model into a model in R. I need to find 3 sets of coordinates which minimizes the distance to the 5 other given coordinates. I've made a program which calculates a distance matrix which outputs the minimal distance from each input to the given coordinates. I want to minimize this function by changing the input. Id est, I want to find the coordinates such that the sum of minimal distances are minimized. I tried several methods to do so, see the code below (Yes my distance matrix function might be somewhat cluncky, but this is because I had to reduce the input to 1 variable in order to run some algorithms such as nloprt (would get warnings otherwise). I've also seen some other questions (such as [GRG Non-Linear Least Squares (Optimization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942574/grg-non-linear-least-squares-optimization)) but they did not change/improve the solution.

```
# First half of p describes x coordinates, second half the y coordinates # yes thats cluncky
p<-c(2,4,6,5,3,2) # initial points

x_given <- c(2,2.5,4,4,5)
y_given <- c(9,5,7,1,2)

f <- function(Coordinates){ 

# Predining
Term_1                       <-     NULL
Term_2                       <-     NULL
x                            <-     NULL
Distance                     <-     NULL
min_prob                     <-     NULL
l                            <-     length(Coordinates)
l2                           <-     length(x_given)
half_length                  <-     l/2
s                            <-     l2*half_length
Distance_Matrix              <-     matrix(c(rep(1,s)), nrow=half_length)

# Creating the distance matrix
for (k in 1:half_length){
  for (i in 1:l2){
    Term_1[i]                <-     (Coordinates[k]-x_given[i])^2
    Term_2[i]                <-     (Coordinates[k+half_length]-y_given[i])^2
    Distance[i]              <-     sqrt(Term_1[i]+Term_2[i])
    Distance_Matrix[k,i]     <-     Distance[i]
  }
}
d                            <-     Distance_Matrix

# Find the minimum in each row, thats what we want to obtain ánd minimize
for (l in 1:nrow(d)){
  min_prob[l] <- min(d[l,])
}
som<-sum(min_prob)
return(som)
}

# Minimise
sol<-optim(p,f)
x<-sol$par[1:3]
y<-sol$par[4:6]
plot(x_given,y_given)
points(x,y,pch=19)
```

The solution however is clearly not that optimal. I've tried to use the nloptr function, but I'm not sure which algorithm to use. Which algorithm can I use or can I use/program another function which solves this problem? Thanks in advance (and sorry for the detailed long question)

Comment: As opposed to reinventing the wheel, can you just use the `kmeans` method to find the 3 centers? `kmeans(data.frame(x_given, y_given), centers = 3)`

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed this. This works perfectly. Although I searched the internet I did not come across this solution. Thank you very much (although reinventing the wheel would have been fun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the output of `optim`.  It reached the iteration limit and had not yet converged.

```
> optim(p, f)
$`par`
[1] 2.501441 5.002441 5.003209 5.001237 1.995857 2.000265

$value
[1] 0.009927249

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

Although the result is not that different you will need to increase the number of iterations to get convergence.  If that is still unacceptable then try different starting values.

```
> optim(p, f, control = list(maxit = 1000))
$`par`
[1] 2.502806 4.999866 5.000000 5.003009 1.999112 2.000000

$value
[1] 0.005012449

$counts
function gradient 
     755       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```